# Converting an array of arrays to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the data shown below and I am working with AngularJS. To access the programs, I do `userData.programs` in my template. However I am having trouble getting the services associated with a user. `userData.programs.services` doesn't work.

```
var userData = 
[  
  {  
    "role":"1",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "id":1,
    "programs":[  
      {  
        "name":"Program 1",
        "id":"PR1",
        "services":[  
          {  
            "name":"Service 1",
            "id":"SVC1"
          },
          {  
            "name":"Service 2",
            "id":"SVC2"
          },
          {  
            "name":"Service 3",
            "id":"SVC3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {  
        "name":"Program 2",
        "id":"PR4",
        "services":[  
          {  
            "name":"Service 12",
            "id":"SVC12"
          },
          {  
            "name":"Service 14",
            "id":"SVC14"
          },
          {  
            "name":"Service 15",
            "id":"SVC15"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "first_name":"John",
    "email":"user@gmail.com",
    "username":"user"
  }
]
```

To access the services, I have tried to manipulate the JS as shown:

```
 var userServices = [];
 for (var i=0; i < userData.programs.length ; i++) {
     userServices.push(userData.programs[i].services);
 }
```

But this results in an array of arrays, that is `[Array[3], Array[3]]` with each array containing 3 objects. I can't access this in my AngularJS template either.

Is there a way I can convert this `[Array[3], Array[3]]` into `[Object, Object]` or is there a way of accessing `services` directly from `userData` in my template?

Edit: putting in my template as well

```
<select id="authorized-programs" kendo-multi-select="" k-option-label="'Select Programs...'" k-data-text-field="'name'" k-data-value-field="'id'" k-data-source="userData.programs" k-ng-model="userProgramIds" k-on-change="change(kendoEvent)">
</select> //This works perfectly as expected

<select id="authorized-services" kendo-multi-select="" k-option-label="'Select Services...'" k-data-text-field="'name'" k-data-value-field="'id'" k-data-source="???????" k-ng-model="userServiceIds" k-on-change="change(kendoEvent)">
</select> //I need the equivalent data source for services as well.
```

Comment: What kind of object do you envision having instead of those `Array[3]`s?

Comment: @Teemu It is! But since I couldn't directly access services from userData in my template, I had to extract the services :/

Comment: @Grundy I've put in my template, hope that helps!

Comment: @JLRishe Objects instead of Arrays is what I'm hoping for if that makes sense. Because I can't seem to access the Arrays from my template.

Comment: @c'estlavie are you want in one select all services from all programs?

Comment: you can do a little change for your code to `userServices.concat(userData.programs[i].services);` then you have one array of objects

Comment: @Grundy that's a great question! But no, I'd like the services associated with a particular program.

Comment: do you can select more than one program? `userProgramIds` is array id or one id?